# Marketing Cloud - SOAP Request to Get Delivery Profiles

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm Trying to get the delivery profiles in one account sending this SOAP Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
soapenv:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
  <soapenv:Header>
  <fueloauth>{token}</fueloauth>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DeliveryProfile</ObjectType>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
       <Properties>ID</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

`Token` was got with a request to `/v2/token`.

The SOAP call to: https://{Subdomain}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx

`{Subdomain}` is my account subdomain.

Header `Content-type: text/xml`.

But I had got `400 Bad Request` as response when I sent the HTTP Request.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that DeliveryProfile Object is [not a retrievable SOAP object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.htm), which is why you both are getting those errors:

[image]

It is also why the [SSJS Core function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_deliveryProfileFunctions.htm) only has Add/Remove/Update options.

I am working on finding out a REST endpoint to gather this information, but so far I have nothing that is available to be shared. It would seem that in current state, delivery profile is unobtainable via API.

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington, If you find, could you please share here or in your blog? I really would like to read!

Answer (score 0):

this is not a correct answer, but too long for a comment.

I can get you one error message further, I believe you need to specify the SOAPAction in the header.
But I have not yet found a way around this next issue. Hope this helps somehow:

POST https://{Subdomain}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx

Headers:

```
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction:"Retrieve"
```

Payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
        </Options>
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DeliveryProfile</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>-->
            <!--<Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Property>Name</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>Default</Value>
            </Filter>-->
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

response:

```
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>Error: Unable to find a handler for object type: DeliveryProfile. Object types are case-sensitive, check spelling.</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>600f4bc0-0711-4b99-8ebc-db1f4e97dec3</RequestID>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

Curiously, the response tells us

```
"Error: Unable to find a handler for object type: DeliveryProfile. Object types are case-sensitive, check spelling."
```

Which is not the same as using a completely wrong ObjectType:

```
"Error: DeliveryProfile123 is not a valid ObjectType."
```