# How to get Send Classification ID, Delivery Profile ID and Sender profile ID in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, marketingcloudapi, email-studio

I am trying to make an API call from Postman to make a test send.

I am trying to implement the solution given here - https://gortonington.com/email-send-preview-and-test-sends-via-rest-api/. I am using the last solution using the Data Extension - (SEND TEST EMAIL – DE ROW PREVIEW) given in the blog.

In the API call I need to pass following information,

```
"sendManagement": {
    "sendClassificationID": "{{sendClassificationID}}",
    "deliveryProfileID": "{{deliveryProfileID}}",
    "senderProfileID": "{{senderProfileID}}"
  }
```

I understand the Key I find in the UI is different from the ID. Please could anyone let me know to how to get this info either using the SFMC UI or RESTAPI would be really helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendClassification & SenderProfile >> Retrieve them through a standard SOAP API RetrieveRequest; You are looking for the ObjectId.
DeliveryProfile is known to not be possible at this stage (unless someone has an update to this: [Marketing Cloud - SOAP Request to Get Delivery Profiles](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306445/marketing-cloud-soap-request-to-get-delivery-profiles))

DeliveryProfile should not be super crucial though - when you have the Send Classification, that references a Delivery Profile and Sender Profile.

this is also stated in the article you link:

> > You will only be required to include the sendClassificationID in order to have the test send function, but the others are nice if you want to utilize something other than the defaults assigned to that send classification.

This is a working retrieveRequest with some generic Properties that all types of Objects have:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
       <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">;
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>SenderProfile</ObjectType>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>ObjectId</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

just replace the ObjectType to get the SendClassification.

```
...
<ObjectType>SendClassification</ObjectType>
...
```

You can find them documented around here;
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/soap_web_service_objects.html

Comment: Thank you very much and it worked